# Connect to more VPNs

Tags: 12.04, vpn

I am using ubuntu 12.04LTS on my vaio laptop and I am in a situation that I have to use two different VPNs to have a good internet access and I don't know how to achieve that.because when I click on a VPN to connect(through Networks->VPN Connections), current connected VPN will be disconnected first.

Comment: Are you trying to multiplex? Wouldn't the bottleneck be your last-mile connection to your (physical) ISP, if you have a good VPN service?

Comment: No, I'm just a user wants to have two connected VPNs together to have access both resources simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only run one VPN using Network Manager. I have to run two VPNs (openvpn) at work, too. I connect to the first with Network Manager and to the second using a terminal. I have installed the byobu terminal emulator for this, because you can detach the vpn session from it (using the F6 key).

Comment: Could you please add more details about your answer,specially about byobu terminal emulator.

Comment: You can use any terminal, e.g. the standard gnome terminal (just type "terminal" in the Dash to find it). To start a openvpn session, navigate to the directory containing your vpn certificates, then type "sudo openvpn <your_vpn>". You will be asked to type first your sudo-password and then your vpn username and password. If you have done everything right, the vpn session will be running until you stop it by pressing ctrl+c in the terminal window. I only prefer byobu because you can close the terminal without stopping the vpn process. It can be installed from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: ,I've done what you said and I get this----> sudo: openvpn: command not found

Comment: Sounds loke you haven't installed openvpn yet. To do so, open a terminal, type "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openvpn". After the installation, try again.

Comment: What is <your_vpn>, because when I write my VPN name in VPN Connections, I get this --> Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: XXX

Comment: Can't tell you. Look through your vpn directory and try the filenames. When it's openvpn, it is most linely a .ovpn file.

Comment: Where is my vpn directory? what do you mean when you say _it's openvpn_? should I make a open vpn first? could you please mention all steps of using openvpn? thanks.

Comment: First you have to find out which vpn-protocol and software your vpn provider relies on. Besides openvpn, there are several other protocols ( which I couldn't help you with). If yours cannot be run from the command line, all this is of no use for you.